# IF EXIST para un campo en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente estoy intentando saber si unas personas son clientes o no, y quiero buscar por nombre si estan en otra tabla

por ejemplo tengo este query

```
SELECT bp.BPId,
       bp.BPTypeCode,
       bpt.DescrLocal DescrBPTypeCode,
       CASE
           WHEN bpt.SystemBusinessProcessTypeId = 15 THEN
               cl.FullnameLocal
           ELSE
               bp.BeneficiaryName
       END Beneficiario,

       INTO #temporal                                     
FROM BusinessProcesses bp (NOLOCK)
```

Misma que estoy guardando en una tabla temporal llamada #temporal para poder realizar la busqueda de si es cliente o no en otra tabla que se llama **Clients**

quiero compara si el nombre del cliente de la tabla #temporal esta en la tabla **clients** entonces que me diga que SI de lo contrario NO, lo estaba haciendo con IF EXIST pero no se si la sentencia sera asi:

```
SELECT 
t.BPId
,t.BPTypeCode
,t.Beneficiario
, IF EXISTS ( SELECT c.FullnameLocal FROM dbo.Clients c INNER JOIN #temporal tt ON tt.FullnameLocal = c.FullnameLocal ) 'Si' else 'No' end AS [Es Cliente]


FROM #temporal AS t
```

Comment: Hola  Marco, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber los **clientes temporales** que estan en la **tabla cliente** puedes hacer esto:

```
select t.BPId, t.BPTypeCode, t.Beneficiario
from temporal t
where t.Name in 
(select c.Name 
 from Cliente c)
```

Aqui haces una **subconsulta** usando el **operador in** el cual para cada nombre de la **tabla temporal**(t.name) comprueba si esta en incluido en los nombres devueltos por la **subconsulta**. De esta forma obtenemos los clientes de la **tabla temporal** que estan en la **tabla Cliente**.

Para saber los clientes de la **tabla temporal** que no estan en la **tabla cliente** usamos el operador **not in**.

```
select t.BPId, t.BPTypeCode, t.Beneficiario
from temporal t
where t.Name not in 
(select c.Name 
 from Cliente c)
```

**Ojo:** Yo asumo que el campo al que tu te refieres se llama **name** en las dos tablas, quiza tu tengas nombres distintos para referirte a esos campos.

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos**

Te comento de la estructura que sería resultante *(si no tienes error de sintaxis alguna)*; tu tabla **`#temporal`** no tiene **`FullnameLocal`** tiene **`Beneficiario`**; sugiero uses **`LEFT JOIN`** de la siguiente forma *(previamente corrigiendo `FullnameLocal`)*:

```
SELECT
 TMP.*,
 CASE WHEN T.BPId IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'SÍ' END EXISTECLIENTE
FROM
 #TEMPORAL T
LEFT JOIN dbo.Clients C ON C.FullnameLocal=T.FullnameLocal
```

Te puede ser útil el siguiente link del `CASE`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869227/sql-server-case-statement-when-is-null